# Kotlin : Type mismatch: inferred type is Intent? but Intent was expected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am new to Kotlin and I have an error like this in my `onActivityResult` method

'Type mismatch: inferred type is Intent? but Intent was expected'

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode  != REQUEST_CODE)
            {
                return
            }
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Screen cast permission denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }
        mediaProjectionCallBack = MediaProjectionCallback()
        mediaProjection = projectionManager!!.getMediaProjection(resultCode,data)
        mediaProjection!!.registerCallback(mediaProjectionCallBack,null)
        virtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay()
        mediaRecorder!!.start()
    }
```

Error is in this line when I use data from `onActivity` result it gives me an error which I mentioned above:

```
mediaProjection = projectionManager!!.getMediaProjection(resultCode,data)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin there are nullable types, `Intent?` and `Intent` aren't the same type.
`data:Intent?` means that your `data` can be `null`.

`getMediaProjection(resultCode:Int, data:Intent)` method wants your data to be of type `Intent` which means it can't accept `null` values. So you have to either cast it to not-null value with `!!` operator or check if it is not null:

```
if(data != null){
    mediaProjection = projectionManager!!.getMediaProjection(resultCode,data)
}
```

In this case automatically knows that data is not null, so it doesn't throw error.

Comment: either solution it still gives me an error


`1.java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {no.realitylab.arface/no.realitylab.arface.FaceRegionsActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections`


`2.Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION` @Tuqay

Comment: Yes, on the same line @Tuqay

Comment: This error you get is not the same as the last one, I am sorry  I can't help you, I recommend posting question with this new error. Have a good day